# Why is Szeth allowed to sully his grandfather’s reputation?

Tags: character-motivation, cosmere, stormlight-archive

Szeth says in *The Way of Kings* that, as he is Truthless, he doesn’t go by Szeth-son-Neturo, so as not to insult his father. Instead he goes by Szeth-son-son-Vallano. Why is it alright, in his mind, to go by his grandfather’s name instead?

<sub>please mark spoilers for anything after *The Way of Kings* :-)</sub>

Comment: I don't think there's any details that would directly shed light on this. Probably book 5 will get more into Szeth stuff. As far as speculation goes it's quite possible that's because grandfather's dead or maybe Szeth didn't like him or even didn't knew him...  I thinks it's anyone's guess by now.

Comment: Another thing is that I doubt he's "not allowed", it's just his own decision. I think there's some indication in 4th book that father was particularly important for him, perhaps he saw him as an exemplar, who's not to be tarnished.

Answer (score 1):

He's not. Technically. Szeth is still going by his father's name, except he's replaced the name Neturo with son-Vallano, as they are synonyms. In other words, he's not calling himself 'Szeth the son of the son of Vallano', he's calling him self 'Szeth the son of 'The Son of Vallano'', using his father's alternate title.

I don't have Word of Brandon for this, I'm just basing it off my knowledge of historical naming conventions.

Comment: But aren’t those two meanings the same?

Comment: From a certain point of view, yes, Vallano is mentioned. From my point of view, his name is being used as a substitute name for Neturo, and thus does not bear the full shame of being directly mentioned.

Comment: They are not synonyms at all.  His fathers name would have been "Neturo son-Vallano"; son-Vallano would be more of a generational surname, not his name itself.   "Szeth son-Neturo" would actually tell you the name of Szeth's father, whereas "Szeth son-son-Vallano" wouldn't necessarily tell you anything about which of Vallano's children was Szeth's father.  They have different meanings and  are not directly synonymous.